# GIT - Visual Studio 2013 - Issue committing work

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

We have recently switched to Git from TFS.  For some reason we are experiencing a lot of work lost due to this.  We have been using the plugin with VS.net.

Recently we faced a situation where we had lost an entire file along with code changes.  Can someone explain how this has happened?

I did the following steps

1. Committed the changes (**Commit A**)
2. Pulled the latest
3. Merged the code to ensure the changes were good
4. Pushed all the code to the master

What I don't understand is when I did **Commit A**, it did include that file.  If  the merge somehow removed that file, I would expect it to show the file in **Commit A** and deletion in the merge.  There was no record of this file in **Commit A** Also, this was not a new file.  I am not sure why it would delete the file locally.

As of now, we are moving to Mercurial due to the amount of issue with Git and VS.net.

But I would like to understand how this could happen and what we could do to prevent it in the future, whether it is a user issue and/or settings issue.

Comment: This question needs a title. The title right now is just a copy of the tags.

Comment: After merging, how did you get back to **Commit A** again? Did you revert back?

Comment: basically the developer didnt check in his code for 5 days.  a huge dont do.  Basically he lost those 5 days of work.  So commit a was the same as b, plus it deleted a file.